# Zend Form and own inuput

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I use Zend Form to create form, but i want to add own inputs between `<form>` and `</form>`. 
Is it possible ? Sample code:

```
$form = new Form_file()
$table = new DataTables();
$table->add('id');
....
$table->add('input type="checkbox" name="f" value="1"');
$this->view->form = $form;
```

How to add DataTables to form with Zend Form?

Comment: What else did you try? Custom element, decorator?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Cant you add all the elements you need and then remove them in your controller if they are not needed for that particular controller?

Comment: You need to add the input elements yourself and that bind the form to the row data.